# traceroute does not show local proxy hop

Tags: traceroute, proxy-server

I'm using Ubuntu and the proxy settings is set to forward traffic to a local proxy on another PC in my home LAN.
Here is the setup:

[image: My setup]

Ubuntu settings:
[image: My PC settings]

When tracing the packets from my PC, why traceroute dose not show Proxy Server in the list?

Here is the result:
[image: traceroute result]